# Query IN statement

Tags: mysql

I am trying to do a query for my mysql db. I have a column that has a comma separated value. I need to do a WHERE statement search with a value to see if it returns results.

```
lets say my column has a value of: = "value1, value2, value3"

"SELECT * FROM table WHERE column_name IN('value1')"
```

Problem is there is no results.

I don't want to do a "like" query as even a value22 would come up?

So how do I properly do a query of a comma separated column by searching with one value?

Thank you.

Comment: You should not store values in the table like you did. That mean bad architecture, that makes issues like you expecting in the feature. Normalizing DB first thing what you have to do to escape them.

Answer (score 0):

`LIKE` (or `ILIKE` if you need case-insensitive) can do the job

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE
  (column_name LIKE '%value_1,%' OR column_name LIKE '%value_1') AND
  (column_name LIKE '%value_2,%' OR column_name LIKE '%value_2') AND
  (column_name LIKE '%value_3%,' OR column_name LIKE '%value_3')
;
```

Comment: Thank you. I was worried that LIKE would not always be exact. Like it will query if is still has additional text at the end of the value? Like lets say value is Test...It will still query if the value is Tester ?

Comment: This doesn't work, As I need an exact match. the % wild is not exact.

Comment: Actually the best solution would be to use `REGEXP` in replacement to `LIKE`. There are a lot of edge cases to watch over: lists of no element, one, and multiple elements; keys matching first element in the list, in the middle, and in the end; repeated keys (if they happen). Ultimately split the `REGEXP` into three clauses to simplify individual key matching.

Comment: On top of that, this column is poorly design, usually you want to have a higher normal form so as to query them properly.